# Is it possible to index embeded objects in MongoDB with Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, sphinx

I have an app built on Rails3 and talking to MongoDB via Mongoid.
I wan't to search on one of my models and it's embedded children using Sphinx.

I'm using [mongoid-sphinx](https://github.com/huacnlee/mongoid-sphinx) gem, to setup search indexes like this

```
class Foo

  include Mongoid::Sphinx
  field :title, :type => String

  embeds_many :bars

  search_index(:fields => [:title])

end
```

Is it possible also to define index on this embedded model `bar`?
Lets assume that `bar` has string field `:content`.

Comment: I think its not possible yet. I'd have to either store Bars as separate collections using referenced keys, or fork this gem and write my own implementation of xml-pipe

Answer (score 0):

Since r3518 there is  support for json attributes .
Please check https://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/detail?r=3518 and especially /trunk/test/test_206/test.xml on how it can be used. Currently searching in json objects is stil experimental ( doesn't support subojects yet).
Not sure if these new attrs work out-of-box with the ruby gem.